# VB6 - How to catch exception or error during runtime

Tags: vb6, error-handling

I developed an application in VB6. In client's environment it raises runtime errors which I can't reproduce under debugger. Is there any way to get the stacktrace or location of error?
I created log file and

> *I used
>   Err.Description,Err.Source*
>   but it gives blank values.

Please help me.

```
 my method(......

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

             .........
    Error_Handler : 
                  writeToLogFile(Err.Source,Err.Description)
```

Comment: You probably know this, but just in case, VB6 is completely unsupported as of March 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788707.aspx I'm guessing you're providing legacy support or something.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. That's not completely correct. The VB6 **IDE** is unsupported but the VB6 **runtime** is supported for the full support lifetime of Windows 7, which is until about 2019 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx

Comment: @MarkJ: **Very** useful distinction indeed, thank you. @OP and other readers: If you don't read the link, just be clear that when they say the IDE, that includes the compiler (e.g., the compiler has been unsupported for more than a year and a half); it's the *runtime* that will continue to be supported through Windows 7 (but not, they say explicitly in that article, beyond that). Cheers again, Mark.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Me again, sorry! The article says "there are no plans to include VB6 runtime in future versions of Windows beyond Windows 7". IMHO that doesn't say they definitely won't support it beyond Windows 7. It just says they haven't made their minds up yet, but in a way that's calculated to try to push people away from VB6.

Comment: That was they same thing they had been saying about Vista prior to Windows 7.  Nothing can be concluded from such a "non-statement" about support.

Comment: @MarkJ & Bob: Fair enough, although given how long it's been since the compiler was unsupported, we have to expect The End is Nigh. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've probably done something to clear the `Err` object before writing to the log file. This is very, very easy to do. What you'll want to do is as soon as you detect an error has occurred, grab the error message before doing *anything* else. Then pass the error message to whatever logging routine you're using. E.g.:

```
Dim sMsg As String

On Error Goto ErrHandler

' ...code here...

Exit Function

ErrHandler:
sMsg = "Error #" & Err.Number & ": '" & Err.Description & "' from '" & Err.Source & "'"
GoLogTheError sMsg
```

Comment: I already did this. but some time Err.Description gives me blank value.

Comment: `Err.Description` can be blank (try this `Err.Raise 1234567` to see that happen), `Err.Number` should always have a value, though.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, thanks for your guys' answers helping me. I'm about half a decade late to the game of VB6. I don't do windows unless forced to. ;)

Anyhow, when doing your error checking, say among 3000 individual record query insertions, I learned a couple tricks. Consider this block of code:

```
'----- order number 1246-------
On Error Goto EH1246:
sSql="insert into SalesReceiptLine ( CustomerRefListID,TemplateRe..."
oConnection.Execute sSQL
sSql="SELECT TxnID FROM SalesReceiptLine WHERE RefNumber='1246'..."
  oRecordset.Open sSQL, oConnection
sTxnId = oRecordset(0)
  oRecordset.Close
sSql="INSERT INTO SalesReceiptLine (TxnId,SalesReceiptLineDesc,Sal..."
  oConnection.Execute sSQL
EH1246:
IF Err.Number<>0 THEN
    sMsg = sMsg & "Order # 1246; sTxnId = " & sTxnId & _
        vbCrLf & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbCrLf
sErrOrders = sErrOrders & "1246,"
End If
On Error GoTo -1
'----- order number 1247-------
On Error Goto EH1247:
```

When not testing for Err.Number, you'll get a 0: on every order handled. (maybe you don't want that). The On Error GoTo -1 resets the error so that it will work again. Apparently, Err only works "once".

I wrote a php script to build the VB6 source code to run some 8000 odbc queries... :P

Comment: On Error Goto 0 is the standard way to clear error handlers.  To "reset the error so that it will work again" use Err.Clear.  Then it will work "more than once."  :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you definitely, positively have an `Exit Function` just above the `Error_Handler:`?

Comment: Oh, nice one, that's a classic mistake. Though you'd expect if he's walking through with a debugger...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Even so... No disrespect meant to Royson, because I know I've certainly overlooked obvious stuff before

Comment: Oh, absolutely. You and me both.

Comment: Interesting, my answer shows inline usage as opposed to the (possibly intended) usage outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    my method(......

        On Error GoTo Error_Handler
........
    Exit Sub
        Error_Handler : 
                      writeToLogFile(Err.Source,Err.Description)
```

"Exit Sub" should be added before you handle the Error_Handler function.....